# Index SE in backTransformed Model - unmarked

Tags: r, unmarked-package

I have an unmarked model, “fm1”. I use backTransform() to see model results to see an interpretable abundance. I know I can use coef()  to pull about abundance and store as a seperate object. How do I index the SE with in the transformed object? Do you know the index position of the SE from the transformed result?

```
fm1 <- pcount(~survey_time ~ 1,
                 data = umf,
                 K=150)

lam <- backTransform(fm1, "state")

lam_coef <- coef(lam)

# How do I pull out SE?
se <- lam[,'SE'} # Does not work

se <- lam@ # hidden in one of these options?
```

```
> lam
Backtransformed linear combination(s) of Abundance estimate(s)

 Estimate   SE LinComb (Intercept)
     1.19 0.31   0.172           1

Transformation: exp
```

Comment: I think `SE(lam)`. I looked at what class those objects are using `class(lam)`, then looked at `methods(class = 'unmarkedBackTrans')` to find extractor methods.